# php insert multiple row in one click in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, row

I have a table called `result` in mySQL. I want to insert a multiple rows one single click. Basically teacher is putting student result in to data base through php:

table: result

entity: result, student_id

Comment: Please add the snippet of your insert statement. No more than 5-7 lines please.

Comment: Moav has showed you the correct syntax (or you could use a `foreach` loop if you're not going to be inserting very many rows)... but please try to be clearer when asking your question. Your use of the term "single click" is very unhelpful as you seem to be discussing PHP and MySQL, neither of which register "clicks"

Answer (score 4):

Your php script will need to construct the insert sql in the following manner (I assume your table T1 has two fields F1 and F2, and the input is v11 v12 v21 v22 etc)

```
INSERT INTO T1 (F1,F2)
VALUES
(V11,V12),
(V21,V22),
...
...
(Vn1,Vn2);
```